# Nginx rewrite and proxy_pass explanation

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location, nginx-config, nginx-ingress

I can see a following locations in nginx/okd configuration:

```
    location /STFlow/ {
        rewrite ^/STFlow(.*)$ $1 last;
#   
#          Are four lines below executed if rewrite has last option ???
#          What's the point of them?          
#
        proxy_pass http://zuul-proxy:8080; 
        proxy_set_header Host      $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location / {
        add_header debug-header dbg5;   
        set $realip $remote_addr;
        if ($http_x_forwarded_for ~ "^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)") {
            set $realip $1;
        }
        proxy_pass http://zuul-proxy:8080; 
        proxy_set_header Host      $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
        client_max_body_size 50M;
    }
```

**In** `location /STFlow/` **are four lines below** `rewrite ^/STFlow(.*)$ $1 last;` **ever executed?**

If so when?

What's the point of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that rewrite rule had a `break` flag instead of `last`, it would remove the `/STFlow` prefix from `/STFlow/some/path` URI before passing it to the upstream, i. e. do the same as the second `location` block except of setting `debug-header` and `$realip` variable. But as far as I understand using the `last` flag makes that four lines never executed, further URI processing would be done inside the second `location` block.

Comment: The same seems to me, but I'm new to nginx and okd, this is first time I have to do with it, and have to do some changes to existing configuration.

Comment: @bastiat Most looks like someone was going to use the `break` flag, but made an occasional mistake.